# How to read in both the Unmarshaled Object and Raw XML for a REST request?

Tags: java, xml, rest, annotations, unmarshalling

I'd like to pull in both the unmarshalled Object and the raw XML as parameters for the REST endpoints primary method.
Doing it w/ just the unmarshalled object or the raw XML seems pretty straightforward, but I'm receiving a run-time exception when it tries to create the REST endpoint.

**What I've Tried:**

```
@Path("/inbound")
public class InboundWs extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    private final static Logger logger = APILogger.getLogger(InboundWs.class);

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response inbound(Inbound request, String rawXml) {
        logger.info("inbound() invloked on text: " + request.getText());
        try {
            service.inbound(
                    request.getSource(),
                    request.getDestination(),
                    request.getText());
        } catch(BadRequestException e) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        } catch(Exception e){
            return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
        return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
    }
}
```

**The Object containing all fields in the XML Request:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Inbound", propOrder = {
    "source",
    "destination",
    "text"
})
public class Inbound {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "source")
    protected String source;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "destination")
    protected String destination;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "text")
    protected String text;

    ....
```

**The Exception:**

```
Feb 29, 2016 1:16:38 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
SEVERE: Following issues have been detected: 
WARNING: Method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response abc.ws.InboundWs.inbound(abc.xml.Inbound,java.lang.String) on resource class abc.ws.InboundWs contains multiple parameters with no annotation. Unable to resolve the injection source.

Feb 29, 2016 1:16:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] Method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response abc.ws.InboundWs.inbound(abc.xml.Inbound,java.lang.String) on resource class abc.ws.InboundWs contains multiple parameters with no annotation. Unable to resolve the injection source.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[application/xml], producedTypes=[text/plain], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class abc.ws.InboundWs, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@1e42af1]}, handlingMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response abc.ws.InboundWs.inbound(abc.xml.Inbound,java.lang.String), parameters=[Parameter [type=class abc.xml.Inbound, source=null, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
```